# Simplify segment list with JTS

Tags: java, geometry, jts

I am testing with the JTS (Java Topology Suite) library to see if I can manage to simplify a list of segments. The truth is I know very little about this library and I'm a programming novice, so I don't know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

What I want is, to transform a MULTILINESTRING list like the following one:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 50 50), (50 50, 100 100, 150 50), (50 150, 100 100, 150 150), (20 20, 80 80), (40 160, 70 130), (110 110, 140 140))
```

Into this:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((40 160, 150 50), (0 0, 150 150))
```

In other words, what I want is to get a list with maximum segments, in terms of length.
Is it possible to make that transformation, and if so, how?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get the answer you suggest purely with JTS methods.  The closest you can get is to:

- node the linework using `Geometry.union()`
- merge the noded linework using `LineMerger`
- simplify the linework using `DouglasPeuckerSimplifier` using a small tolerance

That will give you:

```
MULTILINESTRING ((0 0, 100 100), (40 160, 100 100), (100 100, 150 150), (100 100, 150 50))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Martin!
Best regards.